# CraftMap JS - Not loading map image in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using [CraftMap JS](http://www.jscraft.net/demo/plugins/craftmap/) to produce an "Interactive Map". The map image loads fine in, FireFox and Chrome but no look at all with Internet Explorer.

I have tried this in all versions of IE from 10 down to 7 and the image of the Map just does not load.

I have tried the CraftMap demo, That I linked to above in IE and it works fine. I just cannot see anything obvious that I have missed. So am hoping one of you can help me out.

My HTML markup is as follows :

```
                    <div class="interactive-map">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/assets/img/world_map.jpg?23456897" class="imgMap" />
                    <div class="marker" id="uk" data-coords="933, 340">
                        <h3>United Kingdom</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>(UK) Ltd - Tel: +44</li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="map-more" href="#united-kingdom">Find Out More</a>
                    </div><!-- #uk -->
</div>
```

and my JS....

```
$(function(){

    $('.interactive-map').craftmap({
        image: {
            width: 1994,
            height: 1303,
            name: 'imgMap' // (string) class name for an image
        },
        map: {
            position: '800 10' // (string) map position after loading - 'X Y', 'center', 'top_left', 'top_right', 'bottom_left', 'bottom_right'
        },
        controls: {
            init: true, // (bool) set true to control a map from any place on the page
            name: 'controls', // (string) class name for controls container
            onClick: function(marker)
            {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope someone can help me out, This is driving me crazy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue, By adding a bit of a CSS override. What was happening was an inline style of "height = 0" was added to the map in Internet Explorer.

So in the preloader section of the script I added the following...

```
preloader: {
                init: true, // (bool) set true to preload an image
                name: 'preloader', // (string) class name for a preload container
                onLoad: function(img, dimensions){
                    $('.imgMap').css('height', '1303px');
                }
```

The height I set was matching the height that was set as an inline style in Firefox / Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the issue, but check if all objects are correctly coded. For example:

```
obj = {
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2,
    key3: val3, //comma after last key-value pair
}
```

see the comma after key-value pair? This wouldn't cause any problems at Chrome, Firefox etc, but will raise an error in IE.

Again, just a suggestion, not sure if it's the problem, but check this issue.

Comment: Hi @Alex thanks for the heads up on key value pairings. Unfortunatley no luck with that either. I'm going to have to strip down to match the Demo in terms of naming etc.

Comment: @StuBlackett IE has a debugger, hit F12, maybe you will find whats wrong

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alex I have managed to solve it, Check out answer below if its any good to you. :-)